# CohereAPIError: too many tokens: total number of tokens in the prompt cannot exceed 4081 - received 15416

Tags: python

I have developed a Streamlit app that utilizes the Cohere API for natural language processing. The application allows users to ask questions, and the questions are then processed using the Cohere API. However, I'm running into an issue when the total number of tokens in the prompt exceeds the Cohere API's maximum limit of 4,081 tokens.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.